# How to nill the value of UIPasteboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

1) I copy image from `UIPasteboard` using this method `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;`

2) After creating an image i want to clean the `UIPasteboard`. so i write this method `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = nil;` But this working fine on ios 4 and ios 5 But it gives problem on ios 6.

3) **In my app i want to clean `UIPasteboard` or nil the `UIPasteboard` value. How can i do this on ios 6?**

Comment: What problem do you get with iOS 6?

Comment: It now throws an exception that the argument is not a type of UIImage.  Clearly this is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I currently use

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];
```

Comment: Does this work?  Does it reset the image as well or just the text?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but the accepted answer is just misleading/incorrect. This will not clear the existing value from the pasteboard.

The second argument to `setValue:forPasteboardType:` is a string identifier for the item. As the documentation suggests, it may be a UTI (look in MobileCoreServices) or a user defined string.

The method call in the accepted answer uses `UIPasteboardNameGeneral` which is an identifier for the entire pasteboard itself (and not a key in one if the items in the array of dictionaries in `[UIPasteboard items]`). Since the pasteboard does not contain an item for that key, that call will be a no-op. It is easy to verify this yourself. `[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] name]` is equal to `UIPasteboardNameGeneral`. Also, `containsPasteboardTypes:` using that key will return `NO`.

Now to address what might be happening in iOS 6. Apple is likely using a UTI (say `kUTTypePNG`) as the key for the image data being stored in the pasteboard. They are likely ensuring that the value being set for that key is indeed an NSData (which `nil` is not).

To address your conundrum, may I suggest one of the following:

- If you don't want to share the contents that you put onto the clipboard with other applications, you can create an application specific clipboard using `+ (UIPasteboard *)pasteboardWithName:(NSString *)pasteboardName create:(BOOL)create`

  - The contents of this clipboard will only be accessible to your application and will be deleted when your application is deleted.
  - The contents of the clipboard will be cleared when the app quits unless you set the `persistent` property to YES on the same.
  - You can still access items placed onto the clipboard by other applications by accessing  the general clipboard.
- If you absolutely must clear the contents (given the limitations listed), you can try setting another valid image. I have doubts about this approach since there may be multiple keys for a given clipboard item.

Hope this helps.